# In django, return redirect not giving me the required output

Tags: python, django

I am new to django, I have created a page where only authenticated user should be able to view.

Below is my function which i have made in views.py to check and redirect to login page

views.py

```
def auth_check_manager(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
```

below is the snapshot of url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a decorator that allows you to do this without reinventing the wheel [`login_required`](http://from%20django.contrib.auth.decorators%20import%20login_required). Use it as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(redirect_field_name='my_redirect_field')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```